# REST Create resource with composite id

Tags: java, rest, http, model-view-controller

I have 3 DB entities.
Product - id, name. /products
Order - id, date. /orders
OrderDetail - orderId, productId, price. orders/{orderId}/orderDetails

I am wondering about creating/updating orderDetail entity. For PUT scenario it's clear. I use next url orders/{orderId}/orderDetails/{productId} and pass payload with new price.
But the question is about POST (creating entity) scenario. I should provide both ids (but creating entity usually does not accept id from the user but creates it on the back side), so should the POST method be implemented at all (if yes, how should I provide productId, via url or payload) or I can create and update Order detail using only PUT method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you treat `OrderDetail` as a resource (something you can use HTTP verbs on), you should also give it an identity of its own, not one depending on its values.

With your URL scheme, you e.g. cannot order the same product twice, with different sizes or colors (assuming that the product id is independent of size or color). And you cannot PUT an updated version of the `OrderDetail` if the update changes the product id.

Maybe that flaw comes from a DB table design that (for whatever reason) decided to do without an order detail id, and maybe you can't change that.

I'd either

- give the `OrderDetail` an id of its own or
- make it an element of the (Json?) representation of the `Order` entity, without being exposed as HTTP resource.

A few additional comments:

> I use next url orders/{orderId}/orderDetails/{productId} and pass
> payload with new price.

I'd always pass complete information in the payload, meaning order id, product id, and price, and not rely on a mixture between payload and URL.